# Split SQL server 2008 and Delete

Tags: sql-server

I don't find how to use the results of the split function in SQL. It returns a table and i don't kwon how to do a function like "foreach" to select each return data.

look a the split function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@separator char(1), @value varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@separator, @value)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@separator, @value, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn AS Id,
      SUBSTRING(@value, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS Data
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

it return this :

```
@separator = ','
@value = '13,14,15'

Id Data
1  13
2  14
3  15
```

Then i want to do a thing like that :

```
    DELETE FROM myTable
    WHERE  OneColumnInMyTable = @OneColumnInMyTable AND @ImportantValue = @Data
```

@Data correspond to each value Data in the return of the split.

the aim is to do :

```
    foreach(Data in ReturnOfMySplitFunction)
    {
            DELETE FROM myTable
            WHERE  OneColumnInMyTable = @OneColumnInMyTable AND @ImportantValue = Data
    }
```

Have you some Ideas to do that ? it is possible with the while of sql server ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this using **Split** function.

```
DELETE
FROM myTable
WHERE OneColumnInMyTable = @OneColumnInMyTable
    AND @ImportantValue IN (
        SELECT Data
        FROM dbo.Split(',', @Data)
        )
```

Here i assume your `@Data` contain value like this - `@Data = '11, 12, 14, 15'`

Answer (score 0):

Try the script as below:

```
Delete  A 
FROM MYTABLE A
JOIN DBO.Split(@separator, @value) B ON B.DATA=@Data AND @ImportantValue = B.DATA
Where A.OneColumnInMyTable = @OneColumnInMyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my code if somebody wants to do the same thing :

```
DECLARE @categories varchar(512),
        @GroupingId int,
        @Separator char

SET @Separator = ','
SET @categories = '12,24,33'
SET @GroupingId = '69241'

DELETE FROM RefAssoThematic
WHERE GroupingId = @GroupingId 
AND ThematicId IN (SELECT Data FROM
dbo.split(@Separator,@Categories))
```